# Web firebase authentication doesn't stay logged in when refreshing the page or when redirecting in vanilla JS

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When I log into firebase:

````
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    uid = user.uid;
    console.log('signed in');

    window.location.replace("userdata.html"); // Redirect to data page

    // getData();
    // ...
  })```
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // show error if login fails
    if(errorCode == "auth/user-not-found" || errorCode == "auth/wrong-password") {
      loginError('Username or password was incorrect. Please try again.');
    }
    else {
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);
    }
  });
}
````

user and uid are null after redirecting to the new page, but not before.

I have an observer that prints the uid:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    uid = user.uid;
    console.log(uid)
  }
});
```

Even if I don't redirect and stay on the page, user and uid are both null upon refreshing.

Comment: You should add a `catch()` block in your code. You'll probably see that calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` twice with the same parameters returns an error: you cannot create twice a new account with the same email.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec signInWithEmailAndPassword() signs into an existing account rather than creating a new one. Also, I do have a catch() block-- edited the original post to show. The problem persists.

Comment: Indeed I was totally wrong and mixed it up with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.